# Redirect to a function from a function

Tags: c++

Before answer me, I am learning C++ currently and only have some knowledge about C++.

Here's an example, the user will see a selection of language and the user must type the numbers at the left of languages to choose it, otherwise it will go back to the selection again.

So I have an idea: Put the **main** function at first and the **language** function at last. But the problem is because the **main** function is before the **language** function, so the **main** function cannot find the **language** function and end the program (Of course because of this problem, I can't compile the source code.)

Here's the example code:

```
int main() {
    language();                     // The main function redirect user to the language function
}

int language() {                    // The language() function 
    std::cout << "1 for cookie!";        
    std::cin >> choice;             // Ask user for choice
    if (choice == 1) {
        choice1();                  // If the choice is 1, user will be redirected to choice1() function
    } else {
        main()                      // Otherwise user will be redirected to main and of course, redirect to language() function again
    }
}
```

Because of the problem described above, I got a warning from the Code::Blocks IDE when rebuilt the project:

> error: 'language' was not declared in this scope

Is there is other ways to redirect a user to another function from a function?

**EDIT:** The current answers led me to infinite loop and this is not the result that I want to see. The result that I wish to see is if a user typed an invalid value, it will redirect the user to the function that the user is currently at again, and **the code must be only run ONCE**. (Means not infinite loop)

Comment: Did you *really* call `main()` inside another function?

Comment: You must not call `main` inside a C++ program.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Yes, *but only when user type anything other than 1*

Comment: People will punish me: In IRC the usual answer is: "Get a book!"

Comment: @jrok But how if I need to redirect the user to the selection if they type anything other than the characters I've set in program?

Comment: @DieterLücking And I am learning C++ with a book about learning C++.

Comment: @ngbeslhang Then you make a seperate function for selection and call it. Calling main is very naughty.

Comment: @ngbeslhang Have `language` report the error through its return value. Then use it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've finally know how to use a loop, I found a better and easier solution for asking user to input repeatly until the statment is true.

```
int input;
std::cin << input;

switch(input) {
    case '1':
        // do something...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

while (input != '1') {
    std::cin << input;

    switch(input) {
        case '1':
            // do something...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I've wrote a code that display the menu again after a few tries, but after trying one time I deleted the code and can't do that again. The code above is the similar one without counting how many times did user tried, but since my objective is just redirecting user once user entered a valid value and will not cause the program get into the infinite loop, the code above just works perfect. (I'm using mobile so I don't know if the code above works properly.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare function before first usage.

Also, as noted, per standard, you must not use main within the program:

> The function main shall not be used within a program.

So, create another function and encapsulate the current work inside it!

```
int language(); // DECLARATION

// You could also just define function before first usage:
void do_work()
{
    language();
}


int main() {
    do_work();                     // The main function redirect user to the language function
}

int language() {                    // The language() function DEFINITION
    std::cout << "1 for cookie!";        
    std::cin >> choice;             // Ask user for choice

    // If you enter the invalid input in cin (character for example)
    // you need to reset cin in order to allow user to enter new choice

    std::cin.clear(); 
    // don't forget to include <limits>
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');


    if (choice == 1) {
        choice1();                  // If the choice is 1, user will be redirected to choice1() function
    } else {
        do_work();                      // Otherwise user will be redirected to do_work and of course, redirect to language() function again
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Looping (especially potentially infinite) using recursion (you have an indirect one here: do_work -> language -> do_work) can be dangerous! Please see other answers to get an idea how to solve this with loop statements!

**EDIT** In case you want to check entire line, and not just the first character, you can read the whole line into a string, check if string has lenght 1 (user entered only one character), and than you can switch using the first character:

```
include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int language(); // DECLARATION

// You could also just define function before first usage:
void do_work()
{
    language();
}


int main() {
    do_work();                     // The main function redirect user to the language function
}

int language() {                    // The language() function DEFINITION
    std::string choice;
    std::cout << "1 for cookie!";

    std::getline(std::cin, choice);

    if (choice.length() == 1 && choice.at(0) == '1') {
       choice1();                 // If the choice is 1, user will be redirected to choice1() function
    } else {
        do_work();                      // Otherwise user will be redirected to do_work and of course, redirect to language() function again
    }
}
```

Comment: Note they're calling main.

Comment: This will still lead to potential infinite recursion and thus a crash due to out of stack - try entering A as the input for "choice"... ;)

Comment: This is exactly what I want, support any numbers, letters and symbols. Thanks!

Comment: @ngbeslhang: That was not at all my point - my point was that if you enter A as input, the above code will fail, and get stuck in an infinite loop of calling do_work, which calls language, which calls do_work which calls language, and so on, until it crashes. My suggestion is no different if `language` is ignoring errors in the input when it comes to looping forever, but it won't crash [technically, this code would also crash if it repeats for long enough with valid input].

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks, I will add flushing stdin buffer here.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: I hope you don't mean `fflush(stdin)`. Looping using recursion is bad enough as it is.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I mean `std::cin.clear();        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` Looping using recursion is bad enough as it is, but that was not part of the origianal question, and there are many answers that are pointing that out.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: yes, but it's still a bad idea to use recursion as a method of looping.

Comment: @MatsPetersson This is not exactly what I want to get, I want the redirection that works on any letters, numbers and symbols. (Example: If user type A as input, the program will redirect user to a function and not leading you into infinite loop.)I will try to use **char** instead of **int** to **choice** later and see if it will add support to letters.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "redirection" here. To me, that means something else (changing where output goes, "redirect stdout to foo.txt" would be "myprog > foo.txt"). Do you want the user to be able to enter "A" and "1" and "b" and "z"? If so, use `char`, definitely.

Comment: I think that I still got an issue: When I type **1as** or similar words the program quitted.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Since English is not my mother tongue, I can't really explain to you easily.(Or I mean I can't explain it.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the prototype of your function before the call :

```
int language(); // Declare the function, it is the prototype of the function here

int main() {
    language();                     // The main function redirect user to the language function
}

int language() {                    // The language() function 
    std::cout << "1 for cookie!";        
    std::cin >> choice;             // Ask user for choice
    if (choice == 1) {
        choice1();                  // If the choice is 1, user will be redirected to choice1() function
    } else {
        // main(); // <- You cannot do this !!
        language(); // Use recursive code
    }
}
```

Note that in the code below :

- I added the prototype of the function `language();` before the `main`.
- I changed the call to the `main` who is forbidden by the standard and make your function recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You REALLY do not want to call `main` from another function. In C it is technically allowed, in C++ it is "undefined behaviour" and thus something you should avoid doing.

The solution is instead to put a loop around the call to language in main:

```
int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    do
    {
       result = language();
    } while(result != 0); 
}
```

Then let your `language` function return 0 when it's time to "quit", and non-zero when it should continue.

Comment: @ngbeslhang: Why shouldn't it?  `language()` would return the value that tells `main` whether to go again.  You can make that value pretty much anything you want.

Comment: @ngbeslhang: Not entirely sure what you mean, but it's up to `language` to do what it thinks is right with the input, and return a value to say "we shall continue" or "we shall stop".

Answer (score 0):

use function prototypes, somewhere before main, write code similar to this:

```
void language();
```

then, you can write the code for the function anywhere within the compiled files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like this

```
do //forever
{
    int choice = 0;
    std::cout << "1 for cookie!";        
    std::cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        choice1();
        break;
    }
} while (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to prevent infinite loops when user typed any kinds of characters other than numbers.

```
int main() {
    language();                     // The main function redirect user to the language function
}

void language() {                    // The language() function 
    char choice;

    std::cout << "1 for cookie!";        
    std::cin >> choice;             // Ask user for choice
    if (choice == '1') {
        choice1();                  // If the choice is 1, user will be redirected to choice1() function
    } else {
        language()                      // Otherwise user will be redirected to main and of course, redirect to language() function again
    }
}
```

And also I found that I forgot to add any types for **choice**, sorry about that...

And in the **if** statment, I will use **'1'** instead of **1**, because if I don't use it the program will "think" that this is **not 1** and lead user to **else** statment.

Comment: And what will happen if you type `2` and enter? I think you will be redirected to the `language()` twice. You need to ignore all newline characters.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric But I didn't know how to ignore all newline characters by according to my experience.