# Display the output when type specifed word as first letter and ignore the other words after it

Tags: c++

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211800/redirect-to-a-function-from-a-function?noredirect=1#comment26693629_18211800) question I figured out that using `char` as input will avoid the infinite loop caused by typing characters for input which is using `int`. But now I had met another problem.

When I typed the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
void language();

int main() {
    language();
}

void language() {
    char choice;

    // Ask user for something and input        
    std::cout << "Press 1 to exit the program\n\n";
    std::cin >> choice;

    // Getting user's input and run the code below and find for specific words
    switch(choice) {
        case '1':
            std::cout << "\n\nEnding program...";
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "\n\nPlease type the specific number.\n\n";
            language();
            break;
    }
}
```

When I compile it I didn't get any errors or warnings. But when I type **12** or similar word with **1** at first, the program will be ended.

And before answering me, I still learning C++. (By the way I don't think I really need to say this?) And because this I didn't know how to solve this. What's happening to my code?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you enter input starting with `1`?  What do you expect the program to do in general?

Comment: Nemanja Boric's answer on your other question already correctly shows how to solve this.

Comment: @MarioRossi If I enter the input starting with 1 the program will exit. And I want the program to redirect user who entered anything starting with 1 to the **else** statment.

Comment: @hvd I don't want to use **int** is because I don't want the user being led to infinite loops caused by entering a character

Comment: @ngbeslhang Nemanja Boric's answer does not have that problem, even though it uses `int`.

Comment: @hvd EDIT: So I didn't added **#include <limits>** as Pierre Fourgeaud's answer commented what will this works.

Comment: @hvd After adding **#include <limits>**, the code is working to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want a `char` from the input, [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) will just get the first character you type in the input and assign to `choice`. It will ignore the following characters.

That is, you will enter in the first case of your `switch/case` condition and `return`.

It depends on what are the inputs you expect from the user. If you expect only numbers, I suggest you to use an `int` :

```
#include <limits>    // needed for std::numeric_limits

void language() {
    int choice;
//  ^^^^

    // Ask user for something and input        
    std::cout << "Press 1 to exit the program\n\n";
    std::cin >> choice;

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Getting user's input and run the code below and find for specific words
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "\n\nEnding program...";
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "\n\nPlease type the specific number.\n\n";
        language();
        break;
    }
}
```

[**Working live example**](http://ideone.com/LIxH1a).

Comment: But when I typed some random inputs based on characters and numbers the system said there's an error when running with my inputs(Infinite loop). I even tried another times and it led me into infinite loop.

Comment: @ngbeslhang That's weird. You saw in the example I gave you that it working with different input like a char for example.

Comment: But I used your input and tried it, it does work. But how about the other characters?

Comment: @ngbeslhang Can you give me your inputs ? I will tried and see how to fix it.

Comment: Since hvd told me at one of my question there's an answer that match to my requirements and adding **#include <limits>** (You told me that **std::numeric_limits** need it), I've got my problem solved.

Comment: @ngbeslhang Yes, look at my code, I use `std::numeric_limits` too :)

Comment: While the author of answer commented remember to add '#include <limits>', I didn't saw the comment. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exiting when you enter input starting with character `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the choice as string, not char since char only contains one character. Also you don't need break after the return statement

Answer (score 0):

`char choice;`

will just receive a single character from standard input.

so all digits starting with 1 will end your program

instead use `int choice;` and change case to `case 1:`

```
    #include<limits>
    //...

    int choice;
    //...   
    std::cout << "Press 1 to exit the program\n\n";
    while(true)
    {
        if (std::cin >> choice)  
          break ;
        else {
            std::cout<<"Not an integer !"<<std::endl;
            std::cin.clear() ;
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
                     '\n') ;
        }
     }

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            //...
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "\n\nPlease type the specific number.\n\n";
            language();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: But how if I want to ignore infinite loops caused by user entered a character when I am using **int** as the type of **choice**?

Comment: @ngbeslhang got it , check now

Comment: then I got 2 errors: **'cout' in namespace 'std' dosen't name a type** and **expected unqualified-id before 'while**.

Comment: @ngbeslhang Ahh.. you might have missed something.
Check it from [here](http://ideone.com/BqYKbh)

Comment: Maybe, but can you use ideone.com for online example? Since I am learning C++ and didn't figured out part of your code.

Comment: Still got error when typing s,e and 12 for input. Infinite loops.

Comment: @ngbeslhang Could you please post your code at (ideone.com) and give the link ?

Comment: Um... What you mean? The answer I got from my another question like I said at Pierre Fourgeaud's answer?